# Alternately login after register in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

ok, I'm trying to login the users after success registration into their panels. the database line built successfully. but alternately user login become successful but once not.
Here is the Request Controller Code:

```
    $request->merge(['phone'=> '09123456789']);
    $request->merge(['name' => 'User']);
    $request->merge(['password' => 'pass123456789']);
    $request->merge(['email' => 'user@email.com']);

    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/',
        'password' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
    ]);
    User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'phone' => $credentials['phone'],
        'password' => Hash::make($credentials['password'])
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect()->route('panel');
    }
```

The Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'phone',
    'email',
    'password',
];
```

let me know if I didn't describe perfectly

Answer (score 0):

First, I would stop using validation in the controller and use form request validation instead. It's been the standard since Laravel 5.

Try this simplified code [using `Auth::login()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticate-a-user-instance) instead:

```php
public function createUser(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:64',
        'phone' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/',
        'password' => 'required|string|max:64',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:64',
    ]);

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    ]);

    Auth::login($user);
    return redirect()->route('panel');
}
```

Comment: the merge was for making my point simple

Comment: the problem still exist :/